# Access the first item from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of disabled input field created via ng-repeat **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ip2fTfmnmtAJFQDfW7e3?p=preview)**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="name in names">
   <input type="text" disabled value="{{name.item}}"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make the first input field not disabled ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) and check the [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive's `$first` variable:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="!$first" value="{{name.item}}"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could similarly check for `$middle`, `$last`, `$even`, and `$odd`.  If you use `$index`, you can check for arbitrary row indexes.

Since `ng-repeat` creates an isolated scope, in the case of a nested `ng-repeat`, if you want only the first item in the first parent to be enabled, the relevant code would look like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in names">
      <input type="text" ng-disabled="!$parent.$first || !$first" value="{{name.item}}"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

where you access the outer scope's `$first` (or `$index`) variable through the inner `ng-repeat`'s `$parent` variable.  I created a [fork of your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3abQpviGc5RR4cz0qmcB?p=preview) that shows how this can be done.

Comment: Wow that's just perfect !! :)

Comment: Also thanks for so details answer. It will also help others I am sure.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [$index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). So, just check if the current `$index` is not the first "0th":

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="name in names">
   <input type="text" ng-disabled="$index != 0" value="{{name.item}}"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not just use `$first`?

Comment: Here is more details :
http://plnkr.co/edit/UrWOuYlRpGxXEscIT2wL?p=preview

If you see the example you will notice because of double ng-repeat first item of other groups also becoming enabled. But I want only the first item of first group

Answer (score 3):

This is what you're looking for!

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="!$first" value="{{name.item}}"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can see the [documentation for `ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for more special variables like `$first`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In addition what about for more complex one like

 <div ng-repeat="item in items.">
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="name in names">
       <input type="text" disabled value="{{name.item}}"/>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>

How I can disable the  first item in this case

Comment: You remove the "!" from "!$first". "!" is javascript for "not" :)

Comment: Sorry here is the details:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UrWOuYlRpGxXEscIT2wL?p=preview

First item of every group becoming enabled but I am wanted only the first item of first group to be enabled